# libGDX - no audio on Samsung Galaxy S2

Tags: java, libgdx

Sound effects and music in a game I'm developing are working fine on desktop and on my other test device (ZTE-BLADE) but am getting no audio on my Galaxy S2. Has anyone come across this issue? I've updated the phone's firmware to Android 4.1.2 which is the latest official update for this model. I'm not doing anything outside the norm regarding initialisation, assignment, and playing:

```
public Music titleMusic;
public Sound selectSound1;

titleMusic = Gdx.audio.newMusic(Gdx.files.internal("music/TitleMusic.ogg"));
selectSound1 = Gdx.audio.newSound(Gdx.files.internal("sounds/Select1.ogg"));

titleMusic.play();
selectSound1.play();
```

Comment: How are you implementing sound functionality? Code?? Logs??

Comment: I've added code to my OP to show what I'm doing.

Answer (score 0):

You can try and compile another games made by LibGDX like this one https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx-demo-superjumper. I suppose if your problem continuous even after downloading a compiled LibGDX game the problem maybe caused by your device.